# Displaying Data as a String in Simulink RT Display Port

Tags: matlab, serial-port, simulink

My issue involves using the RS-232 Simulink RT blocks.

A model is uploaded to the target PC (xPC) and it transmits and receives data from a variable frequency drive (VFD) that controls a motor. The issue arises on the receiving end when I take data and try to send that data to a display block in my model as a string. Code would be helpful here:

```
disp = uint8(zeros(1,24));
display = uint8(zeros(1,length(disp)));
cmd = 0;
status = stat_lb;
%% Start-Up 
% Initialization Period
if (status == 0 || status == 1)
    cmd = 0;
    msg = uint8('Start up');
    display = [msg uint8(zeros( 1, length(disp)- length(msg) ))];
end
...
%Multiple status cases with unique displays.
...
disp = display
```

So, here the `cmd` portion functions as expected. As noted above, I want to display the `display` string on a display block in my Simulink model. As you can see, though, it is of type `uint8`, so I need to convert it to type `string`; however, when I pass it through either the `ascii2str` Simulink block or just place it in the function call (e.g. display = ascii2str(display)) I get the following error message:

*Executing the 'CheckData' command produced the following error: Invalid parameter/value pair arguments*

My thought is that this has something to do with the fact that I am using MEX and this function (`ascii2str`) is not supported. Anyways, I am wondering if anyone knows why I receive this error and if there is anything I can do to resolve it.

Oh, and one last thing: I can get the display to work if I just remove the `ascii2str`; however, the only problem with this is that the display is in uint8 form and not really helpful. So, if there is any other way that I can decode the uint8 to a string I am all ears.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have found that there is no support for this feature in Simulink RT. One option is to use external functions, but I found it better for my application to simply output a number and have a table in the simulation that explained what each number meant.